# How to use stdout and stderr io-redirection to get sane error/warning messages output from a program?

Tags: bash, zsh, io-redirection

I have a program that outputs to stdout and stderr but doesn't make use of them in the correct way.  Some errors go to stdout, some go do stderr, non error stuff goes to stderr and it prints way to much info on stdout.  To fix this I want to make a pipeline to do:

1. Save all output of `$cmd` (from both stderr and stdout) to a file `$logfile` (don't print it to screen).
2. Filter out all warning and error messages on stderr and stdout (from warning|error to empty line) and colorize only "error" words (redirect output to stderr).
3. Save output of step 2 to a file `$logfile:r.stderr`.
4. Exit with the correct exit code from the command.

So far I have this:

```
$!/bin/zsh
# using zsh 4.2.0
setopt no_multios

# Don't error out if sed or grep don't find a match:
alias -g grep_err_warn="(sed -n '/error\|warning/I,/^$/p' || true)"
alias -g color_err="(grep --color -i -C 1000 error 1>&2 || true)"
alias -g filter='tee $logfile | grep_err_warn | tee $logfile:r.stderr | color_err'

# use {} around command to avoid possible race conditions:
{ eval $cmd } 2>&1 | filter
exit $pipestatus[1]
```

I've tried many things but can't get it to work.  I've read "From Bash to Z Shell", many posts, etc.  My problems currently are:

1. Only stdin goes into the filter

Note: the `$cmd` is a shell script that calls a binary with a `/usr/bin/time -p` prefix.  This seems to cause issues with pipelines and is why I'm wrapping the command in `{…}` all the output goes into the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original post was mostly correct, except for an optimization by Gilles (to turn off `set -e` so the `|| true`'s are not needed.

```
#!/bin/zsh
# using zsh 4.2.0
setopt no_multios
#setopt no_errexit # set -e # don't turn this on

{ eval $cmd } 2>&1 |
tee $logfile |
sed -n '/error\|warning/I,/^$/p' |
tee $logfile:r.stderr |
grep --color -i -C 1000 error 1>&2
exit $pipestatus[1]
```

The part that confused me was the mixing of stdout and stderr led to them being interleaved and the `sed -n '/error\|warning/I,/^$/p'` (which prints out from and error || warning to the next empty line) was printing out a lot more than expected which made it seem like the command wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have zsh available.

I did notice that your `{..}`'d statement is not correct.

You always need a semicolon before the closing `}'.

When I added that in bash, I could prove to my satisfaction that stderr was being redirected to stdout.

Try

```
{ eval $cmd ; } 2>&1 | filter
# ----------^
```

Also, you wrote

> Save all output of $cmd (form stderr
>   and stdout) to a file $logfile

I don't see any mention of $logfile in your code.
You should be able to get all output into logfile (while losing the specficity of stderr stream), with

```
yourCommand 2>&1 | tee ${logFile} | ....
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: `{ eval $cmd }` works under zsh. `$logfile` appears in the `filter` alias.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use aliases in scripts, use functions (global aliases are especially looking for trouble). Not that you actually need functions here. You also don't need `|| true` (unless you're running under `set -e`, in which case you should turn it off here). Other than that, your script looks ok; what is it choking on?

```
{ eval $cmd } |
tee $logfile |
sed -n '/error\|warning/I,/^$/p' |
tee $logfile:r.stderr |
grep --color -i -C 1000 error 1>&2
exit $pipestatus[1]
```

I'm also not sure what you meant by the sed expression; I don't quite understand your requirement 2.

Comment: Hi Gilles, the sed line prints out all lines with 'error' or 'warning' in it and all line that follow until an empty line.  This does the first half of requirement 2.  THe other half is with the 'grep --color ... 1>&2'

Comment: Gilles, thanks for the tip about `|| true`.  I had `setopt errexit` set (the same as `set -e`).

Comment: the command `p` in `sed` can redirectes matches to `stderr` or file descriptor internally?

Comment: @MamdouhSaeed No. If you want to do something more complicated than reading from stdin and writing to stdout, use awk or perl.